# EmberJS filter array of items as the user types

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am very new to Ember, and trying to write a simple search/filter for array of items in EmberJS, but it seems to harder than it looks. I found a similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404451/text-field-filtering-a-list-using-ember-ember-data), but I can't seem to bind the search input to the function. My example is the defauly Todo App that is on EmberJS website.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="todos">
{{input type="text" id="search-todo" placeholder="Search Todo List..." value=searchTerm}}
.....
</script>
```

In my `App.TodosController` I have

```
searchResult: function(){
    var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm');
    if(!searchTerm.trim()){return;}
    var regExp = new RegExp(searchTerm);
    return this.get('content').filter(function(item){
        return regExp.test(item.get('title'));
    });
}.property('searchTerm','@each.title')
```

but when I type, nothing happens. I tried to add the `searchResult` to the `actions` hash of the controlller, and I see the function get called when I add `action= searchResult` to the script tag, but I nothing happens.  Basically, I just want a simple [filtering of the list like AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter#searchTextResults), and I want it to be not only over `title` but all of the content, and I don't need it to be a separate route, if it has to be in a separate route, I still don't know how to accomplish this.

http://jsbin.com/AViZATE/20/edit

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve it by adding the `observes` keyword.

Here is a link to the solution http://jsbin.com/AViZATE/37

```
searchResult: function(){
        var searchTerm = this.get('searchTerm');
        var regExp = new RegExp(searchTerm,'i');
        this.get('model').set('content',this.store.filter('todo',function(item){
            return regExp.test(item.get('title'));
        }));
    }.observes('searchTerm')
```

And in Html I have

```
{{input type="text" id="search-todo" placeholder="Search Todo List..." value=searchTerm}}
```

Comment: Where is searchResult called. I see the working example but my version is not working correctly.

Comment: @IanSteffy adding the .observes('searchTerm') at the end of the function means the function will be called whenever the searchTerm property of the controller changes.

Answer (score 0):

The "Ember way" to do this is to create a custom view that listens to the keyUp event (or [any other event](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_adding-new-events)) and sends the search term to the controller's function:

```
Todos.SearchTodoView = Ember.TextField.extend({
 keyUp: function(event){
  this.get('controller').send('searchResult', this.value);
 }                                       
});
```

For some reason I can't get this to work on your [udpated fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AViZATE/35/edit), when I try to acces the controller from the view it returns the view itself. But I know it works since I'm using it in my own app.