# Ember: filter model by text field

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to filter a model by a text field, the filter should be applied as the user types. I am coming from angular (not a pro but I managed to create such a filter there), so I expected this to be easy. Heh.

list.hbs:

```
{{input type='text' placeholder='Filter' size='50' valueBinding='searchKeyword'}}

<ol>
  {{#each model.articles as |article|}}
    <li>{{{article.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ol>
```

I know that this question is asked a lot and I did a lot of research before I decided that the amout of searching is inappropriate for such a problem and that I do not understand some core ideas of ember. It seems like that with the transition from 1.x to 2.x most examples, questions and guides are invalid. My question has been asked multiple times already:

[EmberJS filter array of items as the user types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812401/emberjs-filter-array-of-items-as-the-user-types)

[text field filtering a list using ember + ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404451/text-field-filtering-a-list-using-ember-ember-data)

[Emberjs - Connecting an {{ input }} filter bar with my list of Objects. As I type, the list filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720183/emberjs-connecting-an-input-filter-bar-with-my-list-of-objects-as-i-typ)

but all of the answers use controllers. The docs say that "controllers will be replaced with components". So... how to filter a model the new way?

--

UPDATE

I used Remi's example to create this component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  filteredArticles: Ember.computed('articles', 'filter', function() {
    var keyword = this.get('filter');
    var filtered = this.get('articles');
    if (keyword) {
      keyword = keyword.toLowerCase().trim();
      filtered = this.get('articles').filter((item) => item.get('title').toLowerCase().includes(keyword));
    }
    return filtered;
  })

});
```

the computed property is used as the `{{#each filteredArticles...` argument and setting a property beforehand (which raised a deprecation warning) is not required anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components act pretty similar to controllers in some ways. You can think of them as a combination of controller+view in older ember versions. They still work in current ember. But if you want to make your issue work via components, I would suggest the following:

Lest say, you have a /templates/components/list.hbs:

```
{{input type='text' placeholder='Filter' size='50' valueBinding='searchKeyword'}}

<ol>
  {{#each filteredArticles as |article|}}
    <li>{{{article.title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ol>
```

In one of your templates that should use the components, e.g. /templates/my-list.hbs:

```
{{list articles=model.articles}}
```

Then for your component to work, add a /components/list.js:

```
Ember.Component.extend({
    searchKeyword: null,
    articles: null,
    filteredArticles: null,
    updateList: Ember.computed('searchKeyword', function(){
        var keyword = this.get('searchKeyword');

        var filtered = this.get('articles').filterBy('title', searchKeyword);
        this.set('filteredArticles', filtered);     
    }),
    didInsertElement(){
       this.set('filteredArticles', this.get('articles'));
    }
})
```

Comment: This means that Ember wants me to create lots and lots of components? I would also have to generalize the 'list' component somehow, because the way you proposed it, it's more like a 'article-list' component. Thank you, it's kinda hard to find up to date working examples in Ember.